# Getting NPE on an Instantiated Array of booleans

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Alright, I've been getting a NPE that I can't figure out and it's driving me absolutely batty. I've got a linked list of Reservation objects and a 2d array of booleans to keep track of the available seats:

```
class ResList
{
    private Reservation head;
    private boolean [][] seats;

    ResList()
    {
        head = null; //empty list
        boolean[][] seats = new boolean[5][25];
    }
```

I've also got a method isAvailable() to determine whether a seat is available:

```
boolean isAvailable(int f, int s)
    {        
        if(f<0 || f>4 || s < 0 || s > 24)
            return false;
        else
            return !seats[f][s]; // this line throws the NPE
    }
```

But when I do this:

```
jcbSeat = new JComboBox();        
        for(int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
        {        
            if(list.isAvailable(selectedFlight, i))
                jcbSeat.addItem(i+1);
        }
```

I get a NPE where noted. I added some debugging lines to the ResList constructor, and can access seats[][] there just fine, but when I execute the method, ka-boom: NPE. What is going on here?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I'm just an idiot. This is embarrassing.

Comment: We call that a brain fart.  Everybody has them and it usually requires someone else to point them out to ensure appropriate embarrassmentn  8-)

Comment: For those that want to avoid this and have Eclipse (shadow conflicts). Windows->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Naming shadowing and Conflicts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor is initializing a local variable `seats`, not the instance variable `seats`.
Try with :

```
ResList()
{
   head = null; //empty list
   seats = new boolean[5][25];
}
```

Comment: @Mong134 no your not. Its sort of a flaw in the language IMHO (I mean Java explicitly verbose almost every where else). I avoid this by always doing "this.seats=". You can also turn on a setting in your IDE to point these out.

Comment: @Adam Gent, I should've caught it myself. Been working on this project too long.

Comment: I added a comment to the question to how you can turn it on for Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean[][] seats = new boolean[5][25];
```

This line *isn't* setting the class field `seats` -- it's creating a new variable, internal to your constructor.  Instead, do

```
seats = new boolean[5][25];
```

Answer (score 1):

in your constructor remove boolean[][]; you're creating a new (local) variable instead of initializing your instance variable.

What you did is called shadowing variables; hiding an instance variable by shadowing it with a local Variable. It's a common source for hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring (and initializing) a *second* variable `seats` in your constructor, a local variable. That variable *hides* the field `seats`, so the field never gets assigned a value (and will have the default value `null`).

Simply remove the `boolean[][]` in front of your assignment to `seats` to turn your declaration+initialization into a normal assignment:

```
seats = new boolean[5][25];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing the variable wrong. You are creating a local variable not setting the field. Change

```
boolean[][] seats = new boolean[5][25];
```

to

```
seats = new boolean[5][25];
```